# Set indentation to 2 with Eslint and Prettier

Tags: reactjs, frontend, eslint, prettier

I am trying to set the indentation to size 2 in a React project, where prettier and eslint are used. However, in the code file (like app.tsx), when the indent size is 2, there is an error message that goes "ESLint: Insert ··(prettier/prettier)". And when the indent size is 4, the error message changes to "ESLint: Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4.(indent)"

Not sure what goes wrong in my configurations. Much appreciated if someone can take a look. Thanks in advance!

*.prettierrc*

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "bracketSpacing": true
}
```

*.eslintrc*

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "unused-imports"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    // Code Quality
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "dot-notation": "error",
    "eqeqeq": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",

    // Style
    "max-len": ["error", {
      "code": 120,
      "comments": 150
    }],
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "switch-colon-spacing": "error",
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": ["error", "smart-tabs"],
    "sort-vars": ["error", { "ignoreCase": true }],

    // Functions
    "func-call-spacing" : ["error", "never"],
    // Objects
    "key-spacing": ["error", { "mode": "strict" }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      { "vars": "all", "varsIgnorePattern": "^_", "args": "after-used", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ]
    // Arrays
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "**/*.stories.*"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 2],
        "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "profile",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.51.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.51.0",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the `prettier` plugin is conflicting with what you you have set inside `.prettierrc`.

You're already extending prettier using `"plugin:prettier/recommended"`, so you should be able to simply remove the `prettier` plugin from the `plugin` array and the issue should stop.

Comment: Umm I tried removing `prettier` from `plugins` array in *.eslintrc* but that does not help

Comment: Are you using VSCode and setting `"prettier.tabWidth": 4` inside your VSCode settings? Or do you have a .editorconfig file with conflicting properties?

Comment: No, I'm using Webstorm. But quite interestingly, I reopened the IDE and everything's fine now. Thanks for the help!